# Salvar os dados do array e não sua chave

Tags: php, array, cakephp-3

Galera blz...,

Estou editando um campo para salvar no db, eu envio pro edit.ctp o seguinte array

```
$result = array_merge($cones->toArray(), $cda->toArray());
debug($result);
```

//Resultado:

```
[
(int) 0 => 'Valor 1',
(int) 1 => 'Valor 2',
(int) 2 => 'Valor 3'
]
```

//edit.ctp

```
<?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name',
        [
            'empty' => 'Selecione um cone',
            'label' => false,
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $result
        ]);
?>
```

Mas quando eu executo para salvar no banco ele salva o índice e não o valor do mesmo.
Resultado do $this->request->data;

```
[
'name' => '0'
]
```

Sou novo em php, tentei algumas coisas como array_values, e algumas pesquisas mal sucedidas. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar o valor de um array em determinada posição você pode se basear no exemplo abaixo:

```
$valor = $result[0];
```

No caso estou tentando obter valor do primeiro índice em meu array.

Mais informações sobre arrays:
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Comment: Acho que nao ficou bem explicado, no caso do imput o type dele é um select, o usuário vai selecionar uma daquelas 3 e salvar o formulário, mas no banco de dados quando ele salva em vez de salvar "valor 1" ele salva o indice 0

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa que as chaves do array sejam iguais aos valores

```
$result = array_combine($cda->toArray(), $cda->toArray());


//debug
Array
(
    [valor 1] => valor 1
    [valor 2] => valor 2
    [valor 3] => valor 3
)
```